# Redundant Elements Appear in Result when Executing Nested For-loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm writing a program in Python that fetches all possible first moves for X and O. In this program, X goes first and O goes second. Once X and O finish their moves, I want to print all possible states that the game board can be in.

Initially, X can make nine moves since there are nine empty positions on the board; then, O can make eight moves since there are eight empty positions left.
So, when I print the results, I should get 72 results. Instead, I am getting 108 results.

This is because after getting the first move for X, for some reason that I can't figure out, the previous moves for X gets added to the nextStates.nextStates.
Thus, instead of getting 9*8 results, I get (0 + 8) + (1 + 8) + ... + (8 + 8) = 108 results.

I don't know why this is the case since as far as I'm concerned, I'm just using an equivalent of a double for-loop.

```
import copy

class GameBoard:

  def __init__ (self):
    self.SIZE = 3
    self.currentState = [
        [' ', ' ', ' '],
        [' ', ' ', ' '],
        [' ', ' ', ' ']]
    self.nextStates = []

EMPTY = ' '
X = 'X'
O = 'O'

def printBoard(gameBoard):
  for row in range(0, gameBoard.SIZE):
    for col in range(0, gameBoard.SIZE):
      print('[' + gameBoard.currentState[row][col] + ']', end = '')
    print()
  print()

def getNextStatesO(gameBoard):
  for row in range(0, gameBoard.SIZE):
    for col in range(0, gameBoard.SIZE):
      if(gameBoard.currentState[row][col] == EMPTY):
        tempBoard = copy.deepcopy(gameBoard)
        tempBoard.currentState[row][col] = O
        gameBoard.nextStates.append(tempBoard)
  return gameBoard

def getNextStatesX(gameBoard):
  for row in range(0, gameBoard.SIZE):
    for col in range(0, gameBoard.SIZE):
      if(gameBoard.currentState[row][col] == EMPTY):
        tempBoard = copy.deepcopy(gameBoard)
        tempBoard.currentState[row][col] = X
        gameBoard.nextStates.append(tempBoard)
  return gameBoard

def getNextStates(gameBoard):
  gameBoard = getNextStatesX(gameBoard)
  for i in range(0, len(gameBoard.nextStates)):
    gameBoard.nextStates[i] = getNextStatesO(gameBoard.nextStates[i])
  return gameBoard

def main():
  gameBoard = GameBoard()
  gameBoard = getNextStates(gameBoard)
  counter = 1
  for x in range(0, len(gameBoard.nextStates)):
    for o in range(0, len(gameBoard.nextStates[x].nextStates)):
      print(str(counter) + ' X: ' + str(x) + ' O: ' + str(o))
      printBoard(gameBoard.nextStates[x].nextStates[o])
      counter += 1

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the current state. The only thing you are doing is to update the temporary game board, which gets thrown away everytime you finish the execution of `getNextStatesX` or `getNextStatesO`. By changing the state in the current board, the following iteration shows the previous marking.

Also, I'm not sure you can preserve the state by referring to `GameBoard` statically, like you're doing. Always use `self` to refer to the current instance of a class.

Here is a version that displays the 72 possibilities (notice that some modifications are required to actually reflect the rules of Tic-tac-toe):

```
import copy

class GameBoard:

  def __init__ (self):
    self.SIZE = 3
    self.currentState = [
        [' ', ' ', ' '],
        [' ', ' ', ' '],
        [' ', ' ', ' ']]
    self.nextStates = []

EMPTY = ' ' 
X = 'X' 
O = 'O' 

def printBoard(self):
  for row in range(0, self.SIZE):
    for col in range(0, self.SIZE):
      print('[' + self.currentState[row][col] + ']', end = '') 
    print()
  print()

def getNextStatesO(self):
  for row in range(0, self.SIZE):
    for col in range(0, self.SIZE):
      if(self.currentState[row][col] == EMPTY):
        self.currentState[row][col] = O 
        tempBoard = copy.deepcopy(self)
        tempBoard.currentState[row][col] = O 
        self.nextStates.append(tempBoard)
  return self

def getNextStatesX(self):
  for row in range(0, self.SIZE):
    for col in range(0, self.SIZE):
      if(self.currentState[row][col] == EMPTY):
        self.currentState[row][col] = X 
        tempBoard = copy.deepcopy(self)
        tempBoard.currentState[row][col] = X 
        self.nextStates.append(tempBoard)
  return self

def getNextStates(self):
  gameBoard = getNextStatesX(self)
  for i in range(0, len(self.nextStates)):
    self.nextStates[i] = getNextStatesO(self.nextStates[i])
  return self

def main():
  gameBoard = GameBoard()
  gameBoard = getNextStates(gameBoard)
  counter = 1 

  for x in range(0, len(gameBoard.nextStates)):
    for o in range(0, len(gameBoard.nextStates[x].nextStates)):
      print(str(counter) + ' X: ' + str(x) + ' O: ' + str(o))
      printBoard(gameBoard.nextStates[x].nextStates[o])
      counter += 1

main()
```

Comment: The temporary gameBoard is stored as a GameBoard object in the .nextStates attribute of the GameBoard class. This allows me to see the possible nextStates. I don't want to update the currentState because if I were to add a previousState property to the object, GameBoard.nextState.previousState after executing getNextStates(self) would not be the same as GameBoard.currentState before executing getNextStates(self). Furthermore, if we look at your algorithm, the last output gives 8 Xs—which is not a valid state after just 2 plies.

Comment: True. But that is your algorithm. You need to implement the remaining rules of Tic-tac-toe. I am merely allowing the possible the game board update to take place.